# is it possible to change the query parameters in REST API from script editor in SOAPUI?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, groovy, soapui

i am doing load test on this REST API using SOAPUI.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false
```

i ve successfully setup the testsuite and all. my doubt is is it possible to change the query parameters in the REST API url by passing values from the script editor(either javascript or groovy) for the test suite when i perform test?
if so, how should i write the script?

Hope I am clear with my ques.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: sry.. i ve searched but couldn't able to get it.. thats why asking here if it is possible to write such kind of script?? i am just seeking for one to guide me... @Tichodroma

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: searched google and found the we can write scripts using groovy.. but i ve no idea on groovy.. and what i need is i shd be able to change the restapi url query parameters from script editor.. thats y posted here.. sry i am a rookie.. @Tichodroma

Comment: and also i started using soapui from today only @Tichodroma

Answer (score 2):

The parameters are manipulated via the main tab for a REST test request.

The icons look like

- a box with a circular arrow - revert params to default values
- plain box - clear all params
- a plus with some dashes under it - updates this request params from a specified URL

You can dynamically set the values using groovy

If your params look like

```
address  ${address}
sensor   ${useSensor}
```

You can set those values in a groovy script with:

```
context.setProperty("address", "1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA")
context.setProperty("useSensor", "false")
```